# How to override getSession() in spring mvc

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc

I'm working on an web application and have a problem of session storage.

The application is deployed to a cluster, and we place an apache http server to handle load-balancing. So each request may be handled by different node in the cluster. We set out to use Redis(master/slave) as a shared session storage.

My question is how to plug it to Spring mvc, so we can use redis and don't need change our application code.

I find a solution on the internet which uses Filter and HttpServletRequestWrapper:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
        ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    //get sessionId from cookie or generate one if not found        
    filterChain.doFilter(new CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper(sid, request),
            servletResponse);
}

public class CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    String sid = "";

    public HttpServletRequestWrapper(String sid, HttpServletRequest arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    public HttpSession getSession(boolean create) {
        return new HttpSessionSidWrapper(this.sid, super.getSession(create));
    }

    public HttpSession getSession() {
        return new HttpSessionSidWrapper(this.sid, super.getSession());
    }
}
```

I wonder whether I can find an equivalent in spring mvc?

The first one came to my mind is HandlerInterceptor. But not like filter's api, HanlderIntercepor does not handle the chain, so there is no way to pass a custom request to the next interceptor.

Any idea is appreciate, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I found two strategy on this topic:

The first one is extending your web container(such as Tomcat) and There is some mature open source project focused on it already.

The second one is use filter + wrapper. This stratey is web container agnositic.

Personally I prefer the first one because it's transparent to the developers. Let's say we use Weblogic in test/production evironment and we use embedded jetty for development because it's faster and requires less resources. In this situation, developer doesn't have to setup a session storage for development. On the other hand, however, every developer need to setup  a session storage of his/her own if we adopt the second strategy. The alternative solution is provide a shared session storage for development environment or some configurations to swtich the sesson storage strategy(built-in for development, shared for test/production). I think it's easier to perform dependency(configuration) injection via spring than that via raw servlet filter and hence raise this question.

Does anyone know is there an out-of-box implementation of the first strategy for Weblogic by the way?

Comment: Spring is not substituting servlet filters. Handler interceptors are there to intercept handler execution. Your solution via _servlet filter_ + _request wrapper_ is perfect. Is there any reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: @PavelHoral Thank you for the response , I updated question for the reason

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about WebLogic session storage configuration options, but I can comment on the *filter based strategy*.

You can implement the filter to be aware of its environment. You can add configuration for the development, which will say "don't wrap request" and enable wrapping only in *production* (or *test*) environment.

You can implement your filter to be Spring application context aware (check `WebApplicationContextUtils`) or even being managed by Spring's application context (via `DelegatingFilterProxy`). Then you will be able to pull out configuration values or use Spring profiles to set up the filter manually.

Comment: +1. Thank you for reminding me of WebApplicationContextUtils and DelegatingFilterProxy. I was set out to use an ad-hoc singleton to bootstrap an application context in the filter before your answer.